# Current Time (Javascript) In HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, time

Hi currently I had a javascript that display current time. Is a example taken from the internet. How do I go about doing it such that the current time displayed is 5mins behind the actual time. Don't really know how the time works. Tried to change some numbers but to no avail.

Currently this is the code.

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
{   
    var MONTHS = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ],
        DAYS = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

    var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (5 * 60 * 1000));

    $('#date').text(DAYS[date.getDay()] + " " + date.getDate() + ' ' + MONTHS[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear());

    function zeroPad(val) {
        return ((val < 10) ? "0" : "" ) + val;
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        var fiveMinutesAgo = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (5 * 60 * 1000));
        $("#hours").text(zeroPad(fiveMinutesAgo.getHours()));
        $("#min").text(zeroPad(fiveMinutesAgo.getMinutes()));
        $("#sec").text(zeroPad(fiveMinutesAgo.getSeconds()));
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: new Date().getMinutes()-5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to minus no of minutes that you want to...

```
setInterval( function() {
// Create a newDate() object and extract the minutes of the current time on the visitor's
var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
minutes = minutes - 5; // here you can minus or add minutes as per your requirements
// Add a leading zero to the minutes value
$("#min").html(( minutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + minutes);
},1000);
```

**UPDATED**

```
var currDateTime = new Date(),
    hr = currDateTime.getHours(),
    min = currDateTime.getMinutes(),
    dd = currDateTime.getDate(),
    mm = currDateTime.getMonth() + 1,
    yyyy = currDateTime.getFullYear();

//adding pad while getting singles in date or month between 0-9
if(dd < 10){ dd = '0' + dd}     if(mm < 10){ mm = '0' + mm} 

//current date and time as per UTC format
currDateTime = yyyy +'/'+ mm +'/'+ dd +" "+ hr + ':' + min + ":00";
$("#currDateTime").text(new Date(currDateTime).toUTCString());

//minus -5 minutes to actual date and time
currDateTime = yyyy +'/'+ mm +'/'+ dd + " "+ hr + ':' + (min - 5) + ":00";
$("#minusDateTime").text(new Date(currDateTime).toUTCString());

//we are now going to add +5 min to currDateTime
currDateTime = yyyy +'/'+ mm +'/'+ dd + " "+ hr + ':' + (min + 5)+ ":00";
$("#addDateTime").text(new Date(currDateTime).toUTCString());
```

This way you can add or minus no of hours, minutes, days, months, years to specific objects as per requirements..

Let me know for further clarifications?

Hope it would helps!
Thanks

[Here is a JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LY5rg/4/)

Comment: There is a problem if I were to put minutes - 5. because i set 3 function for each hour minutes and sec. if the minutes is less than 5 minutes (eg. 12:03:01) it will show me (eg. 12:03-5:01) how do i solve this??

Comment: @user3128861  - That is why you should subtract five minutes from the `Date` object before you call `getMinutes()`. You can always keep the original `Date` object (which holds the current time) and also have a `Date` object that holds the time minus five minutes.

Comment: @user3128861 - John S is right! See my updated answer in easy way.

Comment: @John S - Thanks for the clarification to him.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var nowMinusFiveMinutes = new Date(Date.now() - (5 * 60 * 1000));
```

Note:

1. Calling `Date.now()` gets the number of milliseconds since
   the epoch (Jan 1, 1970).
2. `(5 * 60 * 1000)` is the number of milliseconds in 5 minutes.
3. You can construct a date by using `new Date(numberOfMillisecondsSinceTheEpoch)`.

UPDATE:

I don't see the need for three separate `setInterval()` calls. Couldn't you update the three elements in one call, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/gvdr6/)?

Comment: @user3128861 - I'm glad this helped, but you shouldn't change your question to what is given in an answer. The question no longer makes sense then.

Comment: sorry my bad. one last question. how do I freeze the time? I tried clearInterval() but it didn't seems to be working

Comment: @user3128861: To clear interval you need to set id and clear that interval. So try to put whole code within one separate function and call it where ever you want to use. Let's say you set function as  `function testInterval() { your date time code here...}` then next to it use **var id = testInterval(); window.clearInterval(id);**. It should solve your problem.

Comment: @user3128861 - I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvdr6/6/) to show how to clear the interval.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the date to time in milliseconds, and subtract 5 minutes worth of milliseconds (1 min = 60k milliseconds = 5 minutes/300k milliseconds).

```
var x = new Date;
x = x.valueOf();
x -= 300000;
```

And then convert that however you wish.

Comment: I want to display a 5 minutes behind time but still kept the current time

Answer (score 1):

The code is setting the minutes on the line

```
 var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
```

You can do

```
var minutes = new Date().getMinutes() - 5;
```

So that time displayed is 5 mins behind the actual time. I would recommend you to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to know more about Javascript `Date`

Comment: how do I go about doing it such that it won't get a negative number. :X